# Wordpress: Check if slug exists in specific custom post type

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm using the code below to check if a slug exists, but it's searching on all post types and I need to check only on a specific custom post type.

```
function the_slug_exists($post_name) {
    global $wpdb;
    if($wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = '" . $post_name . "'", 'ARRAY_A')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if (the_slug_exists($term)) :
    echo 'Ok';
endif;
```

Is it possible to modify this code to search only on a specific custom post type?

Comment: Have you tried `WHERE post_name = '" . $post_name . "' AND  post_type = '" . $post_type . "'"` ?

Comment: Thanks @Chay22. That's exactly what I need. Please reply with this snippet as an answer so I can close this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function the_slug_exists($post_name, $post_type) {
    global $wpdb;
    if($wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = '" . $post_name . "' AND post_type = '" . $post_type . "'", 'ARRAY_A')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
if (the_slug_exists($term,$type)) :
    echo 'Ok';
endif;
```